# shell script - checking multiple lines if value is smaller than

Tags: bash, shell

I have input files (.txt oder .csv)
In this files are different values (sometimes no value -> "").
If ONE of this values is less than 0.001 (or empty -> "") the output should be "UNCONFIRMED".
If every line of the input file contains a value that's greater (or equal? doesn't matter) than 0.001 the output should be "CONFIRMED"

**input-1.csv**

```
"1.23"
"0.01"
```

**input-2.csv**

```
"1.23"
"0.01"
"0.00001"
""
""
"0.75"
```

**output-1.csv**

```
"CONFIRMED"
```

**output-2.csv**

```
"UNCONFIRMED"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and readable format

```
file=input-1.csv
status="CONFIRMED"
minvalue=0.001

for i in $(cat $file)
do
    if [ $(echo "${i//\"/} < $minvalue" | bc) -eq 1 ]
    then
        status="UNCONFIRMED"
        break
    fi
done
echo $status
```

This reads the file line by line, `${i//\"/}` removes the `"` from the variable if any, then it `echo number < minvalue` and pipe to **bc**, which returns true or false. and when the result is true the loop breaks and the status variable is changed to UNCONFIRMED from CONFIRMED.

You need **bc** for this.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -F '"' '
  BEGINFILE {found = 0}
  $2 < 0.001 {found = 1; nextfile}
  ENDFILE {
    output_file = FILENAME
    sub("input", "output", output_file)
    print FS (found ? "UN" : "") "CONFIRMED" FS > output_file
  }' ./input*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csvsql` from the Python-based [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)

```
$ csvsql --no-header-row --snifflimit 0 --query '
    SELECT CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "STDIN" WHERE a < 0.001) 
      WHEN 0 THEN "CONFIRMED" ELSE "UNCONFIRMED" 
    END AS "Status"
' < input-1.csv 
Status
CONFIRMED

$ csvsql --no-header-row --snifflimit 0 --query '
    SELECT CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "STDIN" WHERE a < 0.001) 
      WHEN 0 THEN "CONFIRMED" ELSE "UNCONFIRMED" 
    END AS "Status"
' < input-2.csv
Status
UNCONFIRMED
```

If you want the output to be a quoted string, pipe the result through `csvformat -U1`